# MPI Scatter and Ibcast leads to deadlock

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, message-passing

I have tried to create a simple program that scatters and reduces some simple data between processes in MPI and in the meantime sends a broadcast to other processes in a non blocking way.

Almost all of my tries result in a deadlock and i cannot undestand why since the broadcast call is nonblocking.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <memory> 
#include <random>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int num_tasks;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_tasks);

    const int num_elements = 1 << 10;
    const int chunk_size = num_elements / num_tasks;

    int task_id;
    int local_buffer;
    int num_proc;
    MPI_Status stat;
    MPI_Request req;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &task_id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_proc);



    std::unique_ptr<int[]> send_ptr;
    
    if(task_id == 0){
        local_buffer = 42;
        send_ptr = std::make_unique<int []>(num_elements);
    
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 mt(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution dist(1, 1);
    
        std::generate(send_ptr.get(), send_ptr.get() + num_elements,
                                    [&] {return dist(mt);});
    }
    
    std::cout << "Processor : " << task_id << " declares : " << local_buffer << std::endl;
    
    auto recv_buffer = std::make_unique<int []>(chunk_size);
    
    std::cout << "Before di scatter" << std::endl;
    MPI_Scatter(send_ptr.get(), chunk_size, MPI_INT, recv_buffer.get(), chunk_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << "After scatter" << std::endl;

    int local_result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < chunk_size; i++){
        std::cout << "Processor: " << task_id << " completition: "<<
    ((float)i/chunk_size)*100 << "%\n";
        local_result += recv_buffer[i];
    }
    
    MPI_Ibcast(&local_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
    
    int global_result;
    MPI_Reduce(&local_result, &global_result, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    if (task_id == 0){
        std::cout << "global result : " << global_result << "\n";
    }

    MPI_Wait(&req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    std::cout << "Processor : " << task_id << " recieves the value : " << local_buffer << std::endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to change all the calls in a non-blocking version but often i get wrong results.
Getting rid of the final waits clears the program of any deadlock but at the cost of having also wrong output.

Removing the broadcast results in a correct output with no deadlocks every time

What i needed is simply to have a program that sends a broadcast at the end of the sum and the try and modify it to make so that the first process to finish is the one to send the broadcast

I would also point out that removing Scatter and Reduce function allows the program to finish without deadlocks, i tought the problem might be caused by some sort of interaction between the Ibcast and the Scatter/Reduce op. but to me this does not make a lot of sense since they are working on different buffers and the broadcast is non-blocking

Moving the broadcast call before the Scatter operation also results in the Scatter never being executed and a frozen execution

Comment: Wrong results for what variable?

Comment: which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using? if you are running on several nodes, what is the interconnect? last but not least, how many MPI tasks are you running?

Comment: The wrong variable is local_buffer, if I get rid of the final MPI_Wait some processes might recieve the number sent in the broadcast but most do not, i put the wait the number is sent to every process but most of the time i get a deadlock

I am using OpenMPI, running on a single node with 8 tasks

Comment: you are not allowed to access `local_buffer` before `MPI_Wait()` is invoked. which version of Open MPI are you running?

Comment: I am running 4.1.5 currently

Comment: it works fine on my mac running Open MPI 4.1.5. try `mpirun -np 8 --mca pml ob1 --mca btl self,vader --mca coll self,basic,libnbc ...` to rule out third party modules and see how it goes.

Comment: Using 'mpirun -np 8 --mca coll self, basic,libnbc' seems to have worked, thanks!
I am kinda new to MPI so i didn't know about this components i will read the docs about them immediately

Comment: Did you run the full command on only `mpirun -np 8 --mca coll self,basic,libnbc ...`?
If the latter, that suggests a bug in an optimized collective module. `mpirun -np 8 --mca coll_base_verbose 100 ...` should tell which module is used.